# How to run .netcore method in a separate process?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

My problem is I am invoking a 3rd party method asynchronously and it can sometimes hang or often take a long time to complete but we need to kill it for whatever reason.

- Since it's third party, tasks and cancellation tokens can't be used to
  cancel the computation.
- From what I read Thread.Abort() is evil. Especially since this method will be reading and writing files and making connections to our database
- From what I've seen AppDomain is something I could have used, but this isn't available in .netcore

It seems the only way to execute this method in a way I can kill immediately and safely is to run it in a process and kill that process. But even this I'm not sure is possible. It seems only .exe can be ran by a process.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like `Task.Run( () => { ... }, cancellationToken)` ?? But thats probably not gonna help you a lot, if its stucked in an io operation

Comment: @Tseng, yes exactly, this is what I have now Task.Run( () => { ThirdPartyLibrary.Bar(); }, cancellationToken). The third party library itself doesn't except a token. So even if the token is canceled it continues to process the method to completion.

Answer (score 1):

In .Net 5 and above, [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/destroying-threads) states:

> The Thread.Abort method is not supported in .NET 5 (including .NET Core) and later versions. If you need to terminate the execution of third-party code forcibly in .NET 5+, run it in the separate process and use Process.Kill.

So your understanding is correct and their guidance is that you need to run it in a separate process.

TLDR;

I was looking for how to run a method in a separate process for the purpose of testing and came across some code that the dotnet runtime team uses for testing these scenarios: [RemoteExecutor](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/project/writing-tests.md).  Unfortunately it's not published as a nuget package, but you can find the code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/arcade/tree/master/src/Microsoft.DotNet.RemoteExecutor/).  Additionally someone created a fork of the corefx (obsolete repo) version of it and published it as a nuget package as [Tmds.ExecFunction](https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.ExecFunction).

They use the approach of creating a program that consumes args about the assembly, method and parameters and then do the normal Process.Start to run that program in a separate thread.  The exe then uses reflection to execute the static code.  So in the latest dotnet, this seems to be the best the dotnet development team has at its disposal.  You can only use static methods because it can't marshal objects so getting any result is limited to storing data in some common location.

It's still a separate exe, but would be a reusable way to have one exe deployed that can run any code rather than writing a separate app for each scenario.  It may or may not be the best route for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for `AppDomain` in .net core, it is explained in this [article](http://www.michael-whelan.net/replacing-appdomain-in-dotnet-core/).

long story short:

**In order to replace `AppDomain` Unload event use**:

```
System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += context => InvokeBatchProcessors();
```

this is a part of `System.Runtime.Loader` library.

**`Appdomain` `GetAssemblies`**:

```
public static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetReferencingAssemblies(string assemblyName)
{
    var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
    var dependencies = DependencyContext.Default.RuntimeLibraries;
    foreach (var library in dependencies)
    {
        if (IsCandidateLibrary(library, assemblyName))
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(library.Name));
            assemblies.Add(assembly);
        }
    }
    return assemblies;
}

private static bool IsCandidateLibrary(RuntimeLibrary library, assemblyName)
{
    return library.Name == (assemblyName)
        || library.Dependencies.Any(d => d.Name.StartsWith(assemblyName));
}
```

This is part of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel` package.

**Creating a *Pollyfill* for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies`**:

```
public class AppDomain
{
    public static AppDomain CurrentDomain { get; private set; }

    static AppDomain()
    {
        CurrentDomain = new AppDomain();
    }

    public Assembly[] GetAssemblies()
    {
        var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        var dependencies = DependencyContext.Default.RuntimeLibraries;
        foreach (var library in dependencies)
        {
            if (IsCandidateCompilationLibrary(library))
            {
                var assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(library.Name));
                assemblies.Add(assembly);
            }
        }
        return assemblies.ToArray();
    }

    private static bool IsCandidateCompilationLibrary(RuntimeLibrary compilationLibrary)
    {
        return compilationLibrary.Name == ("Specify")
            || compilationLibrary.Dependencies.Any(d => d.Name.StartsWith("Specify"));
    }
}
```

---

**Note that these are all examples on how to use `AppDomain` in .net core, for any how needs to use the functionality of `AppDomain` in .net core.**

Comment: thank you. Yes even though some functionality of AppDomain remains in .netcore the part I was specifically thinking of, creating new AppDomain instances and invoking code in those instances like here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?view=netcore-2.1 , I believe has been removed.

Comment: The concept of `AppDomain` doesn't  exist anymore in .NET Core (and no plans to ever bring it back). There are some **APIs** on the `AppDomain` class, that are available (like used for assembly scanning).